# How to add texts between fields in cut command's output?

Tags: cut

```
uptime | cut -d " " -f 4,5,6,7 | cut -d "," -f 1,2
```

The output of this command is `1 day, 20:07`.
And I want to add **"Uptime: "** before **"1 day"**.
(I want `cut` to output `Uptime: 1 day, 20:07`)

Is it possible to do it using `cut`?

And yes, I can do it using `awk` (`uptime | cut -d " " -f 4,5,6,7 | cut -d "," -f 1,2 | awk '{print "Uptime:",$1,$2,$3}'`). But I need to know if we can do it using `cut` as well. :)

Answer (score 3):

`awk` may be a better and easier solution for this.

```
 uptime | awk '{sub(/,/,"",$5); print "Uptime: " $3,$4,$5}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert anything with `cut`.

I would suggest using `sed` to insert the `Uptime:` string instead.

```bsh
uptime | sed 's/.*up/Uptime:/' | cut -d, -f -2
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be no. According to the manual, the job of the command is to *print selected text*, not adding text:

> CUT(1)
>
> NAME
> cut - remove sections from each line of files
>
> SYNOPSIS
> cut OPTION... [FILE]...
>
> DESCRIPTION
> Print selected parts of lines from each FILE to standard output.

The closest is to add a custom output delimiter:

> --output-delimiter=STRING
> use STRING as the output delimiter the default is to use the input delimiter

But that's not what you need in this case.